# Quick formula for finding the probability of exactly x of n events happening when all events have a different probability?

Tags: probability

Say that there are 5 events, with probabilities $P(A)=0.24$, $P(B)=0.29$, $P(C)=0.65$, $P(D)=0.12$, & $P(E)=0.82$ What is the easiest way to figure out the odds of exactly 3 of those events occurring?

The way I would solve for them right now would be like this (where $P(ABC)$ means $A$,$B$,& $C$ occur but $D$ & $E$ do not).

$P(ABC)+P(ABD)+P(ABE)+P(ACD)+P(ACE)+P(ADE)+P(BCD)+P(BCE)+P(BDE)+P(CDE) = 
0.24 \cdot  0.29\cdot 0.65\cdot (1-0.12) (1-0.82) + 0.24 \cdot  0.29(1-0.65) 0.12 (1-0.82) + ...$ and so on.

There has to be an easier way, no? 
Thanks!

Comment: There isn't....

Comment: @Batman: There is; see the duplicated question.